# VBA in PowerPoint doesn't work at OneDrive

Tags: vba, powerpoint, onedrive

I have the PowerPoint presentation with VBA. I'm saving this presentation as .pptm or .ppsm file, and on my local computer it work great. But when i'm upload this presentation at OneDrive, the VBA doesn't work. 
Please help me to understand why it happens?

Comment: What do you mean with "Doesn't work"? When, what happens?

Comment: @Mafii When I start slide show i need to enter some text into textbox (input), to pass this slide. But it's doesn't work, i can't focus and enter the text in this textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not support the execution of macros in any Office application while stored on their servers. In addition, ActiveX controls may be removed so whilst you can upload a macro-enabled file and download it in order to run the code, ActiveX controls no longer be available.

References:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-macros-in-Excel-Online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/macro-disabled-after-download-from-onedrive/922006f2-6ddb-4252-a193-c3e2a58fb688

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you could recommend me the way how can I upload it without removing ActiveX controls? Because I planning to share this file.

Comment: Perhaps this has changed or perhaps it depends more on the user's ActiveX security settings than on OneDrive.  I just added an AX control to a slide, uploaded the PPTM to OneDrive, opened it in OneDrive on another PC. The AX control doesn't work, as expected. But when I chose the option to open it in PowerPoint (ie, locally), it does. The file's here, in case you want to try it:  https://1drv.ms/p/s!Am2R87k-gmnphBQjKwxteZpk19vY

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yeah, it work locally, so I can share it without any problem. And you know, i also tried to embed the presentation at my website using iframe, but unsuccessfully. Is there any way to avoid the ActiveX control? I already try to use other online services like Amazon Web Service, Dropbox, Dot.com, but it seems like they all have AX.

Comment: There are various programs/add-ins that convert PPT to other formats (HTML, Flash, etc) that might work better (ie, get around browser security bans on AX controls).  But none of these formats would support VBA macros; if you need those to work, you'll need to let your users download the file and view it in their own copy of PPT.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg. Thank you!